# Proof by induction in the general case where $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+a)$

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I was doing an exercise and instead of proving $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+1)$, I proved it for $P(8), P(9), P(10)$ and then proved $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+3)$. This proves the statement $\forall n \ge 8$, instinctively. However, I wanted to come up with an actual proof of that fact. Hence:

Let $P(n)$ be a statement, with $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Let S be the set $\{n_0, n_0 + 1, \ldots,n_0 + k\}$, with $k$ a nonnegative integer. Suppose: $\forall n \in S, P(n)$ is true. Suppose also that $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n + k +1) $. Then $\forall n\ge n_0, P(n)$ is true.

**Proof**

Consider the set $E = \{n \mod k+1\ | n\in S \}$. $E$ is obviously $\{0, 1,\ldots, k-1, k\}$ (I'm not sure how to prove that). Let $s$ be an integer, $s > n_0+ k$. Let $m = s \mod k+1 $. Then $m\in E$. We have:

$$\exists n\in S,p\in \mathbb{N}, \frac{n}{k+1} = p +m$$
$$\exists q \in \mathbb{N}, \frac{r}{k+1} = q + m $$
$$\Rightarrow r = n + (k+1)(q -p)$$

Since $r > n_0+k$, $q-p>0$. We can see now that :
$$P(r) \Leftrightarrow P(n + (k+1) + \ldots+(k+1))$$
Since $n\in S$, this concludes the proof.

Is the proof correct? I think this must be a standard result, what is the usual derivation?

Comment: It sounds like you need to show that your proposition is true in an expanded base case.  $n_0, n_1,\cdots, n_k$, then by induction $P(n)$ is true when $n\equiv n_i \pmod {k+1}$  and $P(n_i)$ had been demonstrated in the base cases.

Comment: You can make your proof a little 'nicer' by considering as base $\{n_0,n_0+1,...n_0+k-1 \}$. That way, you can work with $k$, rather than $k+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have some complaints about your proof:

Actually, first a suggestion. Let's say the 'base' is the set $S = \{ n_0,n_0+1,...n_0+k-1 \}$. That way, you can just work with $k$ in the rest of your proof, rather than $k+1$. In fact, I'll assume you did just that, and work with $k$ below.

Second, you want to prove something about arbitrary $n > n_0$, but then later on you use $n$ several times, but for something different. So, I recommend using a different variable for that. E.g. say that $E = \{ i \mod k | i \in S \}$. More disturbingly, at the end you say $n \in S$ ... so what happened to the arbitrary number greater than $n_0$ that you want to prove has property $P$?

Third, when you write those three logical statements, it is not clear if that is meant as you declaring all of those three statement being true, or if that is meant as 1 conditional statement, where *if* the first two are true, then the third is true.

So, in the end .. I am a bit lost with your proof. I know exactly what you are *trying* to do ... but your execution, your proof-writing, needs a good bit of improvement.

Now, you asked about the 'usual' derivation ...

The 'usual' proof for why induction works is by a proof by contradiction (or proof by infinite descent):

OK, so assume we have proven the 'base' and the 'step'. Why does this imply that for all $n$ (greater or equal to 'base'), $P(n)$ is true?

Well, suppose there is a number $n$ for which $P(n)$ is not true. This number cannot be any of the base cases (for you know that all those do have property $P$), and so there must be a smaller number $m$ for which $P(m)$ is not true, for if we had $P(m)$, then we would have $P(n)$ (and here of course is where you apply the inductive 'step', whether it is of the form $P(n) \rightarrow P(n+1)$ (weak induction), or $(\forall k < n : P(k)) \rightarrow P(n)$ (strong induction) or $P(n)\rightarrow P(n+k+1)$ (your induction)). But we can apply this same reasoning on that smaller number $m$: there must be a smaller number yet that does not have property $P$, etc. etc. Hence you get an infinite descent of numbers not having property $P$, but that is impossible, because starting with any number $n$, there are only finitely many numbers you can go down before you reach the base case, which you know all have property $P$. So: Contradiction!

Another way of thinking about this (and this is how it is often presented as well) is to say: if there are *any* numbers that do not have property $P$, then there must of course be a *smallest* number $n$ without property $P$. But that cannot be a number from the 'base', and so if you look at the 'step', the only way for $n$ not to have property $P$ is for there to be a smaller number $m$ to not have property $p$, but that contradicts that $n$ was the smallest one. This proof of course very obviously draws the connection between the principle of induction and the natural numbers being well-ordered, meaning that for any subset of numbers there is always a smallest number (and that you do *not* have infinite chains going down).

And so: No, there cannot be a number $n$ for which $P(n)$ is not true given the 'base' and the 'step'.

Now, can you take this proof by contradiction strategy and apply it to your case?

Comment: The method by contradiction is very elegant, I had never seen infinite descent before. Thank you for the feedback on the proof as well!

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite You're welcome !  Infinite descent was apparently a favorite proof technique of Fermat ... he used it to prove the $n=4$ case of Fermat's last theorem. Infinite descent is logically equivalent to strong induction, but it feels like a combination of induction and proof by contradiction. There are also some nice proofs using infinite descent to prove that the square root of 2 is not a rational number.